# how to change ng-model after it's valid

Tags: javascript, angularjs, validation, input, angular-ngmodel

I'm doing a input with ng-model. But I want to keep the original value when someone put invalid number inside the input box. How can I achieve this?
Here's the plunker:
http://plnkr.co/edit/wX7n0jBn1Ek1py4DJHqT?p=preview

In the input box I'm using ng-model to bind the value. Also I specified the type of the input to be number.

```
<input type="number" name="input" ng-model="example.value" min="0" max="99" required>
```

But when I change the input the ng-model also changes. Can I delay this ng-model change until the number is valid? Or can I use ng-change to achieve this? But it seems that the ng-model will change when you change your input so the ng-change cannot capture the original value.

To make things clear, I'll have an example here:

if the current ng-model is 10, And I type 50. It'll change to 50. Then I type 5000 and it'll change to 5000.

If the current ng-model is 10, and I type 'aaa', It'll go back to 10.

The part I want to ask is how to make a copy of ng-model as I can set the ng-model back when I'm using onchange in this input box.

Comment: perhaps you don't want to edit the live model , edit a copy and merge when valid? Objective and demo are not clear

Comment: @charlietfl what I want to achieve is to update the ng-model when it's a valid number.

Comment: @charlietfl And is there any way that I can make a copy of the ng-model?

Comment: if you use `ng-pattern` it won't update ng-model if not valid. Also if you work on a copy and wait for whole object/form to be valid can update original then

Comment: @charlietfl thanks, that's what I want!

Answer (score 0):

Putting you input type number you already validating your model correctly, what you need is to check if your form is valid. Take a look at validation with Angular [here](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/forms).

To make your value change only after input loose focus, use ng-model-options, your input should be like this:

```
<input type="number" name="input" ng-model="example.value" min="0" max="99" required ng-model-options="{ updateOn: 'blur' }">
```

Answer (score 0):

You can always make directive to store last valid value, just add parser:

```
ngModelCtrl.$parsers.push(function(val) {
  if (val) {
     stored = val;
     console.log(stored);
  }
  return val;
});
```

Then when you want you can revert value to last valid one. Example plunk:
http://plnkr.co/edit/XCacrP3Ij4ZCgyYYaoIa?p=preview

Comment: Thanks! this works. However I'm not sure whether I need a directive to achieve this.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know what you want to achieve with it, it's better to disable the save button until the form is valid.

return back to old value will create more problem, say current value is 10, I changed to 50, means valid and changed the value, further I typed to make it 5000, which value you want to return, 10, 5 or 50?

```
$scope.$watch('example.value', function(newValue, oldValue) {
     if(newValue != oldValue){
       //validate
       if(!valid)
           $scope.example.value = oldValue;
     }
   });
```

Comment: So it'll go to 50 first, then go to 5000. As all of them are valid numbers, Also if the current value is 10 and I input 'aaa', it'll go back to 10.

Comment: add watch and check every input, min max range 
$scope.$watch('input', function(oldvalue, newvalue){ ....}

Comment: but the ng-model already changes when I change the input box. And there's no way I can make a copy of ng-model before I change the change box. So the watch will get the change but it'll not change it back to the original value

Comment: change the ng-model value with old value if not valid, what's big deal here

Comment: but how can I get the old value?

Comment: See, I added the watch code, hope it will help you.
Explore more than ask, if you want to lean, best of luck